# Jquery remove drawn line added via jquery svg library

Tags: jquery, svg, line

In my application I have a line drawn from one table cell to another cell through jQuery SVG plugin. Following the steps of the blog post http://www.openstudio.fr/Library-for-simple-drawing-with.html I managed to add it. But at the same time I need to remove that line and draw it on another place when mouse hovers. Is there a method to remove the drawn line or should I follow a different methodology to hide it or remove it ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation the [line function](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html#line) returns an svg `<line>` element, so you should be able to remove it using the standard DOM core method `removeChild()`.

Untested, but hopefully working:

```
var myline = svg.line(parent, x1, y1, x2, y2, settings);
parent.removeChild(myline);
```