# how to draw a line between to table rows with jQuery based on a relation

Tags: jquery, relationship, lines

I'm trying to replicate this image as you can see the HTML has 2 points and a line that connects them between. I did this in photoshop to demonstrate what I would like to achieve. So far most of the CANVAS has not yet helped me to do this. Because i must stablish the exact curvature and height and this relations can be small and big depending of the position of the Table Row relation between another Table.

[image]

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712189/how-to-draw-a-line-between-2-elements-using-jquery-and-refreshing-that-line

Answer (score 0):

I would try Raphael.JS http://raphaeljs.com/ http://raphaeljs.com/curver.html

You can get x/y coords of a DOM element using jQuery's offset http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: Rapaeljs blocks me on a DIV. and im working with a HTML Table styled by Bootstrap. any ideas?

Comment: Absolute positioning? You're going to be coding based off of the x/y coords regardless, so it's really not that bad I suppose

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the quadraticCurveTo function.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Bezier_and_quadratic_curves

If you already have the x,y of your two points you are in good shape.

Your control point would be the peak of the curve.

```
xc = control x

xy = control y

y1 = point 1 y

y2 = point 2 y
```

Keep your `xc` static and calculate `yc = (y2 - y1) / 2`

Comment: I don't have the x,y values. as you can see on the image link. They can vary on position. i think Ralph can be a good option but still how can be both of them related by just adding the on the table row. Example id="idcountry1" id="idcountry2" and get related.

Comment: I assumed you were already able to calculate the x,y as you had mentioned that you were playing with canvas.  Are you saying you are not sure how they are related or are unsure when a relationship exists?